# Whatsapp message doesnt delivered but the profile picture and status are changed

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Hello i have one friend on whatsapp , so i sent to him 2 messeges but he didnt recived them so the messeges were with one check mark, after maybe 24 hours or less , i enter in whatsapp and i see that he changed his photo and status but the messeges are still not delivered (still with single check mark) what is going on ? Am i blocked or something or problem with whatsapp ? (my friend turning off the phone usualy , and im in europe he is in asia maybe because of this or?) ..

Any idea or same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp messages with one check mark even after a long time usually means that the other person has blocked you. But since you can see profile pictures and status updates he hasn't blocked you.

From WhatsApp's official site.

There are a couple of indicators that you may be blocked:

1. You can no longer see a contact's last seen or online in the chat window.
2. You do not see updates to a contact's profile picture.
3. Any messages sent to a contact who has blocked you will always show one check mark (message sent), and never show a second check mark (message delivered).